# Displaying dynamic components when building from IDE : Java

Tags: java, swing

When I write a code for displaying a textfield,label etc. on an event say button click its works fine if I write the whole code and does not work if I drag-drop any components from netbeans.

How do I solve this problem ?

(Updated with codes)

---

Netbeans code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package maual;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author chiyaIDE
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("button");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(panelLayout);
        panelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        panelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(117, 117, 117)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addContainerGap(183, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(71, 71, 71)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(80, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        panel.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
        panel.revalidate();
        System.out.println(i++);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    public static int i;
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panel;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

---

Manual code

```
public static void paste()
{

    frame=new JFrame();
    panel=new JPanel();
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    panel.setSize(400,400);

    Container cp=frame.getContentPane();
    cp.add(panel);

    JButton button=new JButton("Click HERE");
    panel.add(button);

     button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

            panel.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
            panel.revalidate();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Should you be more specific?

Comment: Any code you tried... that shows something does not work?

Comment: From netbeans 
[link]http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/13/idew.jpg/ 

...

Works manually
[link]http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/4/manual1v.jpg/
.

[link]http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/822/manual2k.jpg/

Comment: Netbeans function :
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
        panel.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
        panel.revalidate();
        System.out.println(i++);
    }

---------------
Manual function :

         button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                
                panel.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
                panel.revalidate();
            }
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in layout manager. I don´t like netbeans GUI Designers, i prefered make own design, and this is one of many reasons why:

you create some basic GUI with designer. Later you want to add next component into, but it is not "visible" because of layout. Default is "free design" that means GroupLayout. Change it to other appropriate layer or specify position for JLabel.

Comment: thank you all :)
it worked . 
->
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());